# Return column values between successive rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table returning many columns 2 of which are time stamps representing 'in' and 'out' of a worker's shift. I want to return a third column's values for records that lie inbetween 2 given time stamps. The issue is that I have rows inbetween my 2 timestamp records that I also need the 3rd column values for.

For example:

```
ID       Date     In     Out     Color    Location
====     ====     ==     ===     ====     ========
1        09/20    09:00  17:00   Black    Paris
2        09/21    09:00  NULL    Black    Paris
3        09/21    NULL   NULL    White    London
4        09/21    NULL   NULL    Red      London
5        09/21    NULL   20:00   Blue     London
6        09/22    09:00  NULL    Black    Paris
7        09/22    NULL   NULL    White    London
8        09/22    NULL   NULL    Red      Paris
9        09/22    NULL   17:00   Blue     London
```

In this example, I want all values for the `Color` column for all records that are within a shift that crossed `19:00`. Therefore I want to return the values in `Color` for IDs `2,3,4, and 5` only as only the shift on `09/21` crossed `19:00`.

Comment: Can't you just do `WHERE (In IS NULL OR In < '19:00') AND (Out IS NULL OR Out > '19:00')`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to get the `in` and `out` times filled in, where they are `NULL`.  You can do this with correlated subqueries.

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             (select top 1 in
              from t t2
              where t2.in is not null and
                    t2.id <= t.id
              order by t2.id desc
             ) as RealIn,
             (select top 1 out
              from t t2
              where t2.out is not null and
                    t2.id >= t.id
              order by t2.id asc
             ) as RealOut
      from t t1
     ) t1
where '19:00' between RealIn and RealOut;
```